# How can I use Robotium Test to extract variable value of a Fragment?

Tags: android, robotium

I have a Fragment which sets a certain value inside a Fragment. It does not put it in a UI element but its a stored value. How can I extract his value using Robotium solo object? The examples I see are all about testing UI elements, but what if the value is a variable of the Fragment?

Comment: Perhaps its solo.getView(R.id) that would give me a reference to the fragment?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get a reference to a fragment from within a unit/robotium test?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647787/how-do-i-get-a-reference-to-a-fragment-from-within-a-unit-robotium-test)

Answer (score 0):

I think i cover most of this here: [How do I get a reference to a fragment from within a unit/robotium test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647787/how-do-i-get-a-reference-to-a-fragment-from-within-a-unit-robotium-test)

but there is one thing that does not cover, and that is that you will have to unsafely cast the fragment you receive into the fragment class that you have a method to call in order to get the value or alternatively use reflection on the fragment returned to peek into the internal state (I vote you go for option one)