# How do I get Robotium to recognise views on other fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, testing, robotium

### The Background

I am having trouble with robotium when testing an activity with 3 fragments
The problem is that Robotium will recognise my EditTexts on the first fragment 
 eg 
        `solo.clearEditText(0);`
        `solo.enterText(0, "Maltese Falcon");`
The first fragment has 3 EditTexts on it so when I get to the first EditText in the next fragment I think that it would be referenced by the number 3 reasoning that the first fragment has EditTexts 0 to 2 and the next fragment has EditTexts 3 to ?

### The Problem

But that is not the way it works the 2nd fragment's EditTexts cannot be referenced by any number for example
`solo.clearEditText(3);`
`solo.enterText(3, "Main Sheet");`
**Does Not Work**
[I also make reference to this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647787/how-do-i-get-a-reference-to-a-fragment-from-within-a-unit-robotium-test)

Answer (score 0):

I have found I can use Robotium to reference the actual EditText using the resource Id and use that to set the text

```
EditText linePurposeEditText = (EditText)solo.getView(R.id.edit_txt_line_purpose);
solo.clearEditText(linePurposeEditText);
solo.enterText(linePurposeEditText, "Main sheet");
```

This forces robotium to recognise the edit text that it is required to work on

Comment: Would be interested to see if anybody else has any other solutions or insights